# Rust lifetimes for implementing a trait on nested slices

Tags: rust, reference, slice, traits, lifetime

I want to create a wrapper around (nested) slices for easy operations on multidimensional data, owned by a different struct.
The most basic version of the mutable version of my slice wrapper might look like this:

```
struct MySliceMut<'a> {
    data: Vec<&'a mut [f32]>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> MySliceMut<'a> {
    fn get(&'b mut self) -> &'a mut [&'b mut [f32]] {
        self.data.as_mut_slice()
    }
}
```

Now if I want to implement a trait, for instance AddAssign, Rust does not seem to infer the lifetime of `&mut self` from the implementing type. The compiler complains that `&mut self` might outlive `'a`:

```
impl<'a> AddAssign<MySlice<'a>> for MySliceMut<'a> { // lifetime 'a
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: MySlice<'a>) { // lifetime '1
        let a = self.get(); // lifetime may not live long enough, '1 must outlive 'a
        let b = rhs.get();

        // do inplace addition here
    }
}
```

[Full Code - Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=09b9006b8df42d41e6bb013ab5097e2b)

I tried to figure out the issue with the lifetimes, but can't find it. Would the trait impl require any additional annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct MySlice<'a> {
    data: Vec<&'a [f32]>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> MySlice<'a> {
    fn get(&'b self) -> &'a [&'b [f32]] {
        self.data.as_slice()
    }
}
```

Problem with your code is that `fn get(&'b self)` returns variable with wrong lifetime. Associated lifetime `'a` of `MySlice<'a>` is lifetime of inner slice. Associated lifetime `'b` of `fn get(...)` is lifetime of the `self`. So I guess the function probably should return `&'b [&'a [f32]]` instead.

-- Edited --

Make sure to change `fn get(...)` of `MySliceMut` either.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick answer! That's indeed the solution. The logical mistake I made, when I thought of this solution, was assigning the lifetime 'a to self in get(), when it is instead the lifetime of the inner references.

Comment: I think the 'b should be part of the `fn get<'b>()` signature instead of a generic over the whole impl block.